# Find $A $ in $\sqrt{28}+\sqrt{7}=\sqrt{A}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

I got this problem from an old test paper of mine. I tried working on it today but I couldn't solve it. I tried solving it using logarithms but I didn't get an answer. The problem asks to solve for $A$.Can you guys help me solve this problem?

Here's the problem:

$\sqrt{28}+\sqrt{7}=\sqrt{A}$

Comment: Is it $\sqrt{28} + \sqrt{7} = \sqrt{a}$ and you want to isolate $a$? **Hint:** $\sqrt{28} = 2 \sqrt{7}$. Now think about adding things and squaring things on both sides of the equals sign.

Comment: @Variable yes I want to isolate a

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We know that $28 = 4 \cdot 7$ so $\sqrt{28} = 2\sqrt{7}$.

Hence $$\sqrt{A} = 2\sqrt{7} + \sqrt{7} = 3\sqrt{7} \implies A = 9 \cdot 7 = 63.$$

Answer (score 6):

Even if you don't see that $\sqrt{28}=2\sqrt{7}$, you can do algebra as usual:
$$
A=(\sqrt{28}+\sqrt{7})^2=28+2\sqrt{28}\,\sqrt{7}+7
=35+2\sqrt{28\cdot 7}=35+2\sqrt{196}=35+2\cdot 14=63
$$
More generally, if $\sqrt{A}=\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}$ you have
$$
A=x+y+2\sqrt{xy}
$$

Answer (score 4):

Here is how it works

$$\sqrt{28}=\sqrt{4 \cdot 7}=\sqrt{4}\sqrt{7}=2\sqrt{7}$$

and hence

$$\sqrt{A} =\sqrt{28}+\sqrt{7}=2\sqrt{7}+\sqrt{7}=3\sqrt{7}$$

which leads to

$$(\sqrt{A})^2=(3\sqrt{7})^2 \\
A=9 \cdot 7 =63$$

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help!

Comment: @AugieJavax98: You are welcome. :) Welcome to MSE. You can vote up and check-mark answers. Note the arrows and the check mark next to each answer. :)